# random numbers between 1 and 50; 50 times

Tags: javascript, for-loop, random, output, textarea

I´m almost got it, but it still not working out like I want 
it -- I got s var a = generates an integer between 1 and 50

the integer (result) is output in a textare id("tt4")

but I can't get it done 50 times, I tried to use a for loop // but like I said, I´m 
hanging here...

```js
function add() {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
    document.getElementById("tt4").innerHTML = a + ('\n');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="add()">OK</button>
  <br><br>
  <textarea id="tt4" name="t4"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

I know that the problem is in the for-loop, because 'nothing' hapens with the var i inside the loop // but I can't figure it out

Comment: You forgot to concatenate with the *existing* `innerHTML`.

Comment: This question doesn't deserve downvotes, it's well formatted and the expected result is clearly articulated, although it is a simple typographical error

Comment: it's already working , ty guys, stillt waiting, to accept the answer 15mins :' D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the innerHTML property in order to update the display. You also need to move your random number generation into your loop. Here is a sample:

```js
function add() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
   var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
    document.getElementById("tt4").innerHTML += a + ('\n');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="add()">OK</button>
  <br><br>
  <textarea id="tt4" name="t4"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place the `random()` inside the loop, each iteration generates a new number, otherwise you have the same number. Also `+=` add content, intead of `=`, that assign and replace the content.

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
    document.getElementById("tt4").innerHTML += a + ('\n');
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="tt4" name="t4"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `+=` instead of `=` when setting the `innerHTML` of the `textarea` (which will add more HTML instead of replacing the HTML with the current random number).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="add()">OK</button>
  <br><br>
  <textarea id="tt4" name="t4"></textarea>
  <script>
  function add() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
    document.getElementById("tt4").innerHTML += a + ('\n');
  }
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```